# Clojure clj-time : parse local string

Tags: clojure, clj-time

I have trouble making the interop between java.util.Date and clj-time.

I have first raw data which is an instance of java.util.Date, let's day :

```
(def date (new java.util.util.Date))
```

I want to turn in into a clj-time object so I do :

```
(def st-date (.toString date))
```

Output :

```
"Mon Mar 21 16:39:23 CET 2016"
```

I define a formatter

```
(def date-formatter (tif/formatter "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"))
```

All is here I think.

I so try

```
(tif/parse order-date-formatter st-date)
```

I have an exception which tell me the format is not right.

I tried

```
(tif/unparse order-date-formatter (tic/now))
```

And I have

```
"lun. mars 21 15:50:29 UTC 2016"
```

Which is the same datetime as the java String but in French (my language) with UTC

Wrapping the code for test

```
(defn today-date-to-clj []
  (let [st-date (.toString (new java.util.util.Date))
        date-formatter (tif/formatter "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy")]
    (tif/parse date-formatter st-date)))
```

I seems that the formatter does not work on the string because it's not the same localization, am I right ? How to change it ?

Thanks for the help !

**EDIT**

Someone gave me a far better answer but this almost worked for curious people (problem at "CET 2016" but works for unparse)

```
(def uni-formatter (tif/with-locale (tif/with-zone order-date-formatter (DateTimeZone/forID "Europe/Paris")) java.util.Locale/US))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `String` as an intermediate date representation you should use a direct conversion:

[`(clj-time.coerce/from-date (java.util.Date.))`](http://clj-time.github.io/clj-time/doc/clj-time.coerce.html#var-from-date)

Comment: Ahah thanks I searched a complicated answer, did not see it !

Answer (score 1):

Take a closer look at clj-time's [coerce](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time#clj-timecoerce) functions.

You can pass your `java.util.Date` object to `from-date` or `from-date-time` to get a `org.joda.time.DateTime` and then apply it to your custom formatter:

```
(require '[clj-time
           [coerce :as c]
           [format :as f]])

(->> (java.util.Date.)
     (c/to-date-time)
     (f/unparse date-formatter))
```

Comment: Thnaks too for the answer !